# Javascript: Recalling function inside a class

Tags: javascript

I am relatively new to the programming and I have a mere basic question which have been bothering me (I just can't recall if my instructor told me about this or not)

Is this Same as

```
class Person extends Human {
constructor() { //how to avoid (1)
    super();
    this.gender = male;
    this.name = "shivom"; //we add super since we are using constructor
    }
    printMyname() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}
```

this

```
class Person extends Human {
constructor() { //how to avoid (1)
    super();
    this.gender = male;
    this.name = "shivom"; //we add super since we are using constructor
    }
    function printMyname() {
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}
```

If not, what is the difference between the both? and If anyone can suggest me any related article to read more? (notice the use of function for printMyName in later one)

Comment: Read the [JavaScript documentation of classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can refeer to these links for more information on classes in ES6

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/6jzx1j/why_no_function_keywords_inside_classes/

Answer (score 0):

you will get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` in second one.You can only use function like code below in `class`:

```
class Person extends Human {
  constructor() {
    // Function code
  }
  someFunction() {
    // Function code
  }
  static sayHi() {
    // Function code
  }
}
```

You should read [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) before code